# Angular 7 fails to load images

Tags: angular, angular7

I am getting a 404 error on loading images.

angular.json:

```
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico","src/assets"]
```

`wQueen.png` is located in /assets and copied into every other directory in the entire project.

Even though `wQueen.png` appears in every one of those directories and hundreds of others, and permissions are granted to all files, directories, I only always get 404.

I have tried all of the following:

```
<img width="100" src="wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./../wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../../wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="src/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/src/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="app/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/app/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="src/app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="/src/app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./src/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../src/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./app/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../app/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="./src/app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
<img width="100" src="../src/app/assets/wQueen.png"/>
```

Comment: can you post the screenshot of directory structure where images exist? As you have tried every possible way so there must be something fishy.

Comment: As @Pradeep Jain mentioned, screenshot of directory structure and error log snapshot can be helpful here.
<img width="100" src="/assets/wQueen.png"/> this should work then

Comment: Home
    project
        Chexx
            src
                app
                    assets

Comment: Home/project/Chexx/src/app/assets
Angular is served on 4200, rest calls redirected to 4100.
tsConfig.json:
{'compileOnSave": false,"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"downlevelIteration": true,
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2015",
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
}}

proxy.conf.json:{
"/rest":{"target": "https://localhost:4010","secure": false,"rejectUnhauthorized" : false}} 
}

Answer (score 0):

src/app/assets has to be in the assets section of the config.  Then referenced by app/assets in the html.  Contrary to the documentation.